# Is there any solution to PermissionError:[Errno13] when using voice assistant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, errno

I am currently working on a voice project in python. The program works fine until I say "hello" after the program says "Hello User." It gives me the following **error:**

```
    C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe 
C:/Users/HP/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 39, in <module>
    speak("Hello, how are you?")
  File "C:/Users/HP/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 16, in speak
    tts.save(randFile)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 294, in save
    with open(str(savefile), 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '91252543randomtext98303551.mp3'
```

**Here's the code:**

```
from gtts import gTTS
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
import playsound
import os
import random

r1 = random.randint(1, 100000000)
r2 = random.randint(1, 100000000)
randFile = str(r1) + "randomtext" + str(r2) + ".mp3"


def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    tts.save(randFile)
    playsound.playsound(randFile)


speak("Hello User!")
os.remove(randFile)


def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Sorry, my speech service is down!")
   return said


    if text == 'hello':
        speak("Hello, how are you?")

    if text == 'what is your name?':
        speak("My name is Alex")
```

I  have seen dozens of the solutions for this error and also tried saving the audio file using "randFile" .However, none of the solutions are helpful.

Comment: You're trying to save the file in a directory you don't have write permission to. Try using the `tempfile` module to create a temporary file.

Comment: @Barmar. I tried using temp file, but I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/Documents/PycharmTest/test2.py", line 26, in <module>
    speak("Hello User!")
  File "C:/Users/HP/Documents/PycharmTest/test2.py", line 22, in speak
    tts.save(temp)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 294, in save
    with open(str(savefile), 'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x0424BCA0>'

Comment: `tts.save()` expects the argument to be the filename, `tts.save(temp.name)`

Comment: Make sure you use `NamedTemporaryFile`

Comment: @Barmar. I was saving randFile outside the function speak. After saving randFile inside the function, the problem was solved. Thank you so much for your help!